# has_many relation works on localhost but not server (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a really weird issue, part of my code is working properly on localhost but when I push to heroku, it work differently

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :box
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def put_in_box
        i = Item.find params[:item_id]
        b = Box.find params[:box_id]
        b.items << i
    end
end
```

And this is what really confuse me

This is log from **Local server**

```
Box Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT "boxes.*" FROM "boxes" WHERE ("boxes"."id" = $1) LIMIT 1 [["box_id", "1"]]
Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT "items.*" FROM "items" WHERE ("items"."id" = $1) LIMIT 1 [["box_id", "2"]]
UPDATE "items" SET "box_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "items"."id" = 1  [["box_id", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 16 Jun 2015 09:07:46 UTC +00:00]]
```

But! this is log from **Heroku** server

```
Box Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT "boxes.*" FROM "boxes" WHERE ("boxes"."id" = $1) LIMIT 1 [["box_id", "1"]]
Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT "items.*" FROM "items" WHERE ("items"."id" = $1) LIMIT 1 [["box_id", "2"]]
UPDATE "items" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "items"."id" = 10  [["updated_at", Tue, 16 Jun 2015 09:15:41 UTC +00:00]]
```

Those logs came from same method, same code snippet but behave differently (the log from Heroku server doesn't update box_id).

Do you have any idea what would cause this?

(Sorry if this is kind of silly question, I'm not really a Rails dev so I have no idea how and why this is not working)

**Here is the database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_dev
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: appo_test
  host: localhost
```

**Finally**

Somehow, this the << operand not working while manually assign parent to children works

```
i.box = b
i.save
```

I got it working now on both localhost and Heroku using above code, but still curious to know why << not working

Comment: I wonder if it's already in the box, and that's why it's only updating the updated_at timestamp.

Comment: I was wondering about that too, but somehow, when I call box.items I got empty array

Comment: You have written `b.item << i ` , it should be `b.items << i `, I wonder how it works? It should raise an error, `undefined method 'item' for object box`

Comment: Good spot @SarwanKumar

Comment: Typo in here, sorry.

Comment: I guess it has to do with different databases, show your database.yml

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Heroku log, it seems that the line `b.items << i` does nothing, because the `box_id` attribute of the item does not appear when updating it in the database.

That reminds me of a weird issue I had in a similar case, where the `<<` operator did nothing (and no error), and simply replacing it by `push` solved the problem, so maybe you could try that: `b.items.push i`

The `<<` operator and the `push` method are not exactly equals (however, based on the docs, I think in this situation they should have the same behaviour).

Comment: Thank for the "push" command, never know about this, will try!!